# Does a choice-based conjoint study have to be full profile?

Tags: r, conjoint-analysis

In a Conjoint study, it's difficult for respondents to evaluate more than 6 product attributes at a time.

Often this is solved via the use of Adaptive Conjoint Analysis (ACA), in which the questionnaire is modified for each individual respondent as the survey is being taken. In ACA, it is not necessary to show the full profile -- i.e. all attributes -- of each product. Partial profiles are shown. A study can include up to 30 attributes, but respondents are never asked to consider more than 5 at a time.

However, in order to do ACA, as far as I know of at this time, one must have the survey hosted by a very expensive (e.g. $10,000) conjoint-oriented survey host.

My question is, is it possible to do partial profile Conjoint, without using ACA?

Answer (score 2):

An option to reduce the number of presented profiles is to use 2k [Factorial Design](http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~setia/cs700-F09/slides/lecture11.pdf) to reduce the number of comparisons. In R you can use [conf.design](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/conf.design/conf.design.pdf) library (there are many other 'agricolae', 'AlgDeign'). This is a basic approach, but if you want to go deeper in the topic of the adaptivity ( from ACA ) you can see [Fast Polyhedral Conjoint](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=374460).

You said: "However, in order to do ACA, as far as I know of at this time, one must have the survey hosted by a very expensive (e.g. $10,000) conjoint-oriented survey host." So
you can design design your conjoint analysis (using R ) and apply versatile questionnaires with open source tools (e.g [Limesurvey.com](http://www.limesurvey.org/))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible, you may send details so can do specific answer. I will suggest you to used faisalconjoint package of R, It is useful for all type of conjoint data, and testes with many published data and studies.